# Very simple image upload using jquery ajax to c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, ajax

I am not at all looking for anything fancy. i just want one image from a html file to be selected and on upload should go and sit in the server. I am just not able to make it. I have checked the forum questions and I built up the following code.

HTML Form:

```
 <form id="fileinfo" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="fileinfo">
    <label>Select File</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" required="required" />
    </form>
    <input type="button" id="uploadBTN" value="Upload"/></form>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(function () {
            $('#uploadBTN').on('click', function () {

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);


                $.ajax({
                    url: 'upload.aspx',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#output').html(data);
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                });
            });
        });
```

In the `page_load` of `upload.aspx`, i try to access `Request.Files[0].InputStream` i get

```
`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
```

Can someone suggest where am i going wrong?

Comment: Are you using apache? or you write your own web-server in C#?

Comment: neither. i use IIS. and server is in c#